# C# Windows 8.1 / Get SQLite string query result as variable

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, sqlite-net

How to get the result of this SQLite query result in variable?
I need to access this in my Windows 8.1 application.

```
string queryDB = string.Format("Select * from ContryLookup");
var tempcountryLookUpData = connection.Execute(queryDB);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need reference to [SqliteDataReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite)

```
static void Main() 
{
    string cs = "URI=file:test.db";

    using(SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection(cs))
    {
        con.Open();

        string stm = "Select * from ContryLookup";

        using (SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(stm, con))
        {
            using (SqliteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read()) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetInt32(0) + " " 
                        + rdr.GetString(1) + " " + rdr.GetInt32(2));
                }         
            }
        }

        con.Close();   
     }
}
```

[Credits](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitecsharp/read/)

[**Worth mentioning**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107096/fill-datagridview-from-sqlite-db-c)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an execute procedure called Execute??
One way to do what you want is using the ExecuteReader procedure and return that to a DataReader object. Then use a for loop to traverse the data:

```
string sql = "select * from table";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
       Console.WriteLine(reader["columnName"]);
```